# Bootstrap X-Editable extension for bootstrap table

Tags: jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap-3, x-editable, bootstrap-table

I have this boostrap table that is populated with a .json file generated by ajax/php, all works fine, but im looking to implement X-Editable plugin, to be able to edit this table, since the table is beign populated by this .json I dont really know how to implement .editable() on every cell.

Here is some code

```
$('#y').on('click',function(){

        ajaxPost("www.example.com/productos/get_all.php", {}, function(result){
            $('#tprueba').bootstrapTable('destroy'); //
            $('#tprueba').bootstrapTable({
                url: 'www.example.com/json/products.jsonp',
                columns: [{
                    field: 'id',
                    title: 'ID Producto'
                }, {
                    field: 'nombre',
                    title: 'Nombre/Descripción'
                }, {
                    field: 'tipo',
                    title: 'Tipo'
                }, {
                    field: 'precio',
                    title: 'Item Price'
                }, ]
            });
            $('#tprueba td').editable();
                });

    });

 function ajaxPost(url, parameters, successCallback) {

          $.ajax({
              type: 'POST',
              url: url,
              data: parameters,
              success: successCallback,
              error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                  console.log('error');
              }
          });

      }
```

So what im trying to do is to make all cells editable via the x-editable extension for boostrap table, any suggestions? Thanks in advance..!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/cduicu/3KkZd/ or https://github.com/mindmup/editable-table